# Lens modifying with failure

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In `Control.Lens.Lens`, there is a function

```
modifying :: MonadState s m => ASetter s s a b -> (a -> b) -> m ()
```

which allows the value under a lens on the `MonadState` state to be transformed by a pure function `(a -> b)`.

However, we may want to allow the transform function to fail in `m`, requiring it to have type `(a -> m b)`.

I've looked through the lens library for such a function, but I can't find one, so I implemented:

```
modifyingM l f = use l >>= f >>= assign l
```

Which does the trick, but I was wondering if there is a function already in the lens library that will do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything like that. `ASetter` is defined

```
type ASetter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
```

so it's not powerful enough for the job (and `Setter` can't do it either). It turns out, on the other hand, that a `Lens` is a bit stronger than necessary. Let's consider, then, how to do it with a `Traversal`.

```
type Traversal s t a b =
  forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

So

```
Traversal s s a b =
  forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f s
```

Which `Applicative` do we want? `m` seems like the obvious one to try. When we pass the traversal `a -> m b`, we get back `s -> m s`. Great! As usual for `lens`, we'll actually only require the user to provide an `ATraversal`, which we can clone.

```
modifyingM
  :: MonadState s m
  => ATraversal s s a b
  -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
modifyingM t f = do
  s <- get
  s' <- cloneTraversal t f s
  put s'
```

That's nice because it only traverses the state once.

Even that is overkill, really. The most natural thing is actually

```
modifyingM
  :: MonadState s m
  => LensLike m s s a b
  -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
modifyingM t f = do
  s <- get
  s' <- t f s
  put s'
```

You can apply that directly to a `Traversal`, `Lens`, `Iso`, or `Equality`, or use `cloneTraversal`, `cloneLens`, `cloneIso`, or (in `lens-4.18` or later) `cloneEquality` to apply it to the monomorphic variants.